# Вопрос по теории вероятностей

Tags: математика, теория, теория-вероятностей

Извините за глупый вопрос.
Вот смотрите. Допустим, у нас есть функция плотности распределения вероятностей f(x). Смотрим на ее график. Точке A на абсциссе (одно из значений некой случайной величины) соответствует точка B на ординате. Причем 0<=B=<1. Т.е. f(A)=B. А теперь сам вопрос: а что вообще возвращает функция плотности распределения? Что такое B? Какую характеристику откладывают на оси y? Вероятность? Если да, то тут тоже проблема. Т.к. значений случайной величины бесконечно много, нельзя сказать, что значение 0 мы получим с вероятностью 0.9 (а на графике, к примеру, есть точка (0, 0.9), ведь по этой логике 0+-ε  (где ε крайне малая величина) тоже появится с вероятностью 0.9. И т.д. Тут уже суммарная вероятность равна чуть ли не бесконечности. Да и вряд ли из бесконечного числа всех вещественных чисел выпадет 0.000003142189420214 равно как и 0.000000099321, хотя по графику-то шанс у обоих 0.9.
Да. Нельзя не согласиться с тем, что оценивать вероятность НСВ по одному какому-то конкретному значению есть дело малоперспективное. Я это понимаю. И разумнее бы, конечно, искать вероятность того, что некоторый А попадет в определенный отрезок (а там уже и площадь интегральчиком вычислим) на оси х. Например, при нормальном распределении вероятность попадания в сигма-окрестность матожидания где-то 68%.
Это все понятно и логично. Но вопрос остается все тем же: а что тогда означает 0.1, 0.2, 0.3….0.9, 1 и т.п. на оси ординат? Что есть значение функции? Что, повторюсь, функция возвращает?

Comment: 0<=B=<1 - это неверно. Где Вы такое видели?

Comment: По-моему в википедии понятно всё написано.https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: Именно *плотность* вероятности. Для непрерывной. Для дискретной - по сути, сами вероятности.

Answer (score 3):

> Вероятность? Если да, то тут тоже проблема. Т.к. значений случайной
> величины бесконечно много,

допустим у нас равновероятные значения от 0 до 1

какая вероятность для значения 0.5? правильно - бесконечно малая.

а какая вероятность от 0.4 до 0.6? правильно - 20% или 0,2

а как это получили? взяли график плотности вероятности и подсчитали площадь (проинтегрировали) от 0,4 до 0,6

а если проинтегрировать график от минус бесконечно до бесконечности должно получиться строго 1 (100%)

работая с плотностью вероятности вы никогда не работаете с каким-то одним значением `x`, потому что физически для вас это не имеет смысла, вы работает с диапазонами

взять например нормальное распределение ростов школьников

функция плотности вероятности будет нормальной, но вероятность для роста 170см будет нулевой, потому что у бесконечномалого кол-ва людей такой рост, у кого-то 170,002, у кого-то 169,9998 и т.д. но раз вам нужна точность в 1 см вы интегрируете нормальное распределение от 170 до 171, к примеру

понятно что в жизни мы собираем данные у конечного кол-ва людей и на росте 170 у нас будет какое-то конечное кол-во людей - но с ним мы не получаем непрерывный график плотности распределения, а дискретный, где у нас как бы уже есть интегрирование по сантиметрам и на основании этих данных мы можем вычислить уже сигм и мю для нормального распределения

Comment: Да это-то я знаю, я же именно об этом и писал. Я спрашиваю: а что вообще откладывают на оси y? Что такое, например, f(4.56)?

Comment: плотность вероятности откладывают, а интегрирование по плотности вероятности дает вероятность

Comment: Ну вот что такое, допустим, 0.9 на оси ординат?

Comment: вот вы настырный - :) производная от вероятности, скорость изменения вероятности в данной точке, если уж на то пошло - рассмотрите этот график и график вероятности как производную и интеграл